# AngularJS ng-Route not matching with $location.path()

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I have an ng-route defined like this:

.when('/cms/course/edit/:Id', route.resolve('EditCourse', 'cms/course/', 'vm', true, 'Edit Course'))

The route.resolve is using Dan Wheldon's lazy loading function. I've tested and it isn't the issue.

I have an otherwise like this:
.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });

Other routes work just fine but when I call the above route to do a change like this:

$location.path("/cms/course/edit/" + course.Id);

(which when I inspect it is coming out as "/cms/course/edit/132343" as expected)

It invokes the .otherwise and redirects to the home page instead of the route passed.

If I then go and put in the above route into my browser's address bar directly, it works fine. (http://localhost:535432/cms/course/edit/1234343)  (I have HTML 5 mode enabled).

Note looking at network activity it never loads the partial view for the right page.

What am I doing wrong that's causing this not to match?

Thanks!

Comment: It look like the problem was not the route, if you recently added this route, try with delete cache, o try in incognito mode

Comment: I've tried both and it doesn't work except if you type it directly in the address bar.

Comment: Where are you calling the $location.path() from?

Comment: From a ng-submit method.

Comment: I had a really similar issue and was taking me ages to find it driving me mad. As it turned out, there was a mistake in one of my promises, as soon as I fixed my promise issue the route worked correctly.